# SPFx Office UI React - How to default select user in People Picker

Tags: web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, people-picker

On `componentDidMount` I have received the current logged in user using MSGraphClient. I have saved the object that I received from graph in `fullObject` variable.

I am using below code:

```
<NormalPeoplePicker
    onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
    onResolveSuggestions={this._onFilterChanged}
    getTextFromItem={(persona: IPersonaProps) => persona.primaryText}
    pickerSuggestionsProps={suggestionProps}
    className={'ms-PeoplePicker'}
    key={'normal'}
    itemLimit={1}
    selectedItems={this.state.fullObject}             
/>
```

How can I set this user as a default in the PeoplePicker field?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After component was rendered call another SP REST which change the state of the component and update like this:

```
<CompactPeoplePicker selectedItems={this.props.selectedItems} />
```